# How to use pdf.js ?Any documentation?

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am struggling  hard to understand how pdf.js works.. All demo files works fine . How do I import those feature in my working project ? What all js files needed ? any  good example to start with ? 
I tried  one given in github ,it works fine . 
Even I tried below one

`alert("pdf js  ");
            PDFJS.embed('mydiv_test', 'my local file path', { 
                  selection: true,
                  search: false, 
                  annotations: true,
                  passwordHandler: function() { /* ... */ return password; }
                });`

Nothing works .. I like the pdf.js UI and wanna use it in my project .

Answer (score 0):

So far I found:

1. [Mozilla labs project (General information and links)](https://mozillalabs.com/en-US/pdfjs/)
2. [Github project](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js)
3. [Frequently Asked Questions](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions)
4. [Github wiki](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki)